# when running a batch process via task scheduler batch file process fails

Tags: windows, batch-file, c#

good day, I have a windows batch file that contains the instructions to compile a list of solutions of VS 2013, when I execute the process of my batch my list of solutions compiles without problems. the problem arises when I program a task in the windows task scheduler the solutions do not compile obtaining the following error "error MSB3073: The command" cscript "exited with code 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a permissions issue.
Look at the authority you are using when the script runs, it is probably not the same authority you are using when you run it manually.